# No puedo manipular mi string para tener una secuencia coherente

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ejercicio que me pide que simule una secuencia paso por paso del trayecto del trineo de santa (paso el enunciado):

> Santa está probando su nuevo trineo eléctrico, el CyberReindeer, en una carretera del Polo Norte. La carretera se representa con una cadena de caracteres, donde:

```
. = Carretera
S = Trineo de Santa
= Barrera abierta
| = Barrera cerrada
Ejemplo de carretera: S...|....|.....
```

> Cada unidad de tiempo, el trineo avanza una posición a la derecha. Si encuentra una barrera cerrada, se detiene hasta que la barrera se abra. Si está abierta, la atraviesa directamente.
> Todas las barreras empiezan cerradas, pero después de 5 unidades de tiempo, se abren todas para siempre.
> Crea una función que simule el movimiento del trineo durante un tiempo dado y devuelva un array de cadenas representando el estado de la carretera en cada unidad de tiempo:

```js
  /* -> result:
  [
    'S..|...|..', // estado inicial
    '.S.|...|..', // avanza el trineo la carretera
    '..S|...|..', // avanza el trineo la carretera
    '..S|...|..', // el trineo para en la barrera
    '..S|...|..', // el trineo para en la barrera
    '...S...*..', // se abre la barrera, el trineo avanza
    '...*S..*..', // avanza el trineo la carretera
    '...*.S.*..', // avanza el trineo la carretera
    '...*..S*..', // avanza el trineo la carretera
    '...*...S..', // avanza por la barrera abierta
  ]
  */
```

El código que hice fue este:

```
function cyberReindeer(road, time) {
  // Code here
  let camino = road;
  const secuencia = [];
  const rgxAvanza2 = /*/;
  const rgxAvanza = /.|*/;
  const rgxPara = /|/;
  //un contador para el trineo
  let trineoIndice = 1;
  //una var para saber el anterior del pedazo de camino
  let caminoAnt = ".";
  let i=2;
  let contPared = 1;

  secuencia.push(camino);
  while(i<=time){
      //rgx.test(string)
      if(rgxAvanza.test(camino[trineoIndice])){
        camino[trineoIndice-1].replace("S", caminoAnt);
        caminoAnt = camino[trineoIndice];
        camino[trineoIndice].replace(rgxAvanza, "S");
        secuencia.push(camino);
        trineoIndice++;
      }else if(rgxPara.test(camino[trineoIndice]) && contPared !== 5){
        secuencia.push(camino);
      }else if(contPared === 5){
        camino.replace(rgxPara, rgxAvanza2);
        camino[trineoIndice-1].replace("S", caminoAnt);
        caminoAnt = camino[trineoIndice];
        camino[trineoIndice].replace(rgxAvanza, "S");
        secuencia.push(camino);
        trineoIndice++;
      }
    i++
    contPared++;
  }
  console.log(secuencia)
}
```

El resultado de mi código es totalmente distinto a lo esperado, me da como resultado esta misma cadena siempre: `'S..|...|..'`

Comment: En lugar de regex puedes analizar cada carácter a mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero y más importante es que debes separar elementos en la lógica, porque desde mi punto de vista de esto va el ejercicio, ya que algorítmicamente es fácil. Yo te daré un ejemplo, pero existen muchas formas de haberlo hecho de manera clara y ordenada.

Lo primero es que para `Santa` creamos un estructura sencilla:

```
const Santa = {
    position: -1,
    toString: () => "S"
  };
```

`Santa` cuenta con una sola propiedad `position` que indica su posición en el camino (comenzando fuera de él en la posición `-1`) y una función `toString` para que cuando se imprima este objeto, lo que imprimirá será `S`

Luego para el camino creamos una clase `Ruta`

```
class Ruta {
  constructor(camino) {
    this.casillas = camino.split("");
    this.length = this.casillas.length;
  }
  puedePasar(santa) {
    return this.casillas[santa.position + 1] !== "|";
  }
  abrirBarreras() {
    this.casillas = this.casillas.map(a => a === "|" ? "*" : a);
  }
  toString(santa) {
    return this.casillas.with(santa.position, santa).join("");
  }

}
```

Donde en su constructor recibe el string que hace de camino, toma este argumento y lo convierte en un array donde cada carácter sería una casilla y además guardamos el largo de dicho array que siempre será el mismo

Además creamos una funciones que nos ayudarán en la lógica

- `puedePasar`: Función que recibe a `Santa` como argumento y retorna `true/false` si es que `Santa` puede ocupar la siguiente casilla
- `abrirBarreras`: Función que cambia los `|` por `*`, abriendo las barreras
- `toString`: Función que recibe a `Santa` como argumento y retorna un string que representa el camino, mostrando a `Santa` en su ubicación

---

Si te fijas con todo esto tenemos gran parte de la lógica resuelta y ordenada; ahora solo se necesitamos un par de `if` y poco más.

Demo:

```js
class Ruta {
  constructor(camino) {
    this.casillas = camino.split("");
    this.length = this.casillas.length;
  }
  puedePasar(santa) {
    return this.casillas[santa.position + 1] !== "|";
  }
  abrirBarreras() {
    this.casillas = this.casillas.map(a => a === "|" ? "*" : a);
  }
  toString(santa) {
    return this.casillas.with(santa.position, santa).join("");
  }

}

function cyberReindeer(road, time) {
  const Santa = {
    position: -1,
    toString: () => "S"
  };
  
  const Camino = new Ruta(road);
  const secuencia = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < time; i++) {
    if (i == 5) Camino.abrirBarreras();
    if (Camino.puedePasar(Santa)) Santa.position++;
    
    secuencia.push(Camino.toString(Santa));
  }

  console.log(secuencia)
}

cyberReindeer('...|...|..', 10)
```

Comment: muchas gracias! si tenes razón todavía tengo esos errores para hacer código claro y legible, seguire mejorando eso!!!! por otra parte me diste otro punto de vista para el ejercicio te agradezco mucho